# Executable (.exe) called by ASP.NET crashes and stops

Tags: asp.net, exe, threadpool

I have a C# ASP.NET Framework 3.5 web application that calls an executable that generates PDF from HTML via "Process".

Sometimes this executable locks and stops working, it only resolves giving recycle in the Application Pool, this does not happen very often.

I'm ending the Process correctly, I've done everything, try/catch with close and dispose in the finally, I've also tried using "using" to open new Process. Nothing solved.

It seems to be an Application Pool issue with the "exe" as if the executable was stuck, is there any setting in the application pool to get around this?

I've already researched the Application Pool and haven't found anything relevant to solve the case.

Comment: Your best bet is to do a memory dump at the time this occurs and then use DebugDiag or WinDbg or some other tool to figure out what is causing the hang.

Comment: Why are you calling an executable from an ASP.NET app to generate a PDF? Generally your website shouldn't be invoking exes. Just too much of a pain, and a security hole. There's so many great alternative ways to do this. You could do a Hangfire background worker in your site, you could have a Windows Service app running listening for a queue message (like RabbitMQ or Azure Service Bus), or serverless function (AWS Lambda, Azure Function etc) to generate it.

Comment: Hello @Igor , thanks for the feedback, this problem only occurs in my client. I asked because it might be a known issue to Application Pool with ".exe". I'll try to convince them to run some diagnostic tool, thank you.

Comment: You don't have to run the diagnostic tool on site/on the live process. If you do a memory dump (available from the windows task manager) you can then load that dump into a tool for diagnosis. That can happen on any PC and does not have to be the server that originally hosted the process.

Comment: Also if you want to run a process out of context consider using something like [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) instead. You could also use a scheduled console job if you do not want to change your code and have it use a pickup directory and/or export directory to do processing. That will also ensure isolation between the processes and you could even run that on it's own machine.

Comment: Hey @mason this is a legacy application, making changes to improve takes time and nobody wants to pay for this time, neither the customer nor my boss.

Comment: good idea Igor, separating things might actually solve my problem, it's not the solution I wanted but it helps